# how to calculate the gridview rows and show the answer into text box

Tags: sql, vb.net

i am trying to calculate the gridview rows value and want to show in textbox. 
I have 5 rows in gridview , itemid , itemname,orderedqty,price,totalprice. when ever I click add the rows here, I want to calculate total amount of totalprice. want to show it to textbox.

what I was trying this is the code ,I think it will not work. please help me to find solution.

```
Public Sub Calculate()
    Dim Countrow As Integer = 1
    Dim AmountTotal As Decimal = 0

    For Each row As DataGridView In dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows
        Countrow += 1
        AmountTotal = dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows.Count.ToString()
    Next
    'GridView1.FooterRow.Cells(1).Text = "Total = " & AmountTotal.ToString()
    txtGrossTotal.Text = AmountTotal.ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to calculate?

Comment: calculate the totalprice row.

Comment: showing error in this line -----For Each row As DataGridView In dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows----------------------------------
(Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'.)

Comment: amounttotal+=row.cells(4).value this line not accepting."cells is not a member of system.windows.forms.datagridview"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like This

```
   Public Sub Calculate()
        Dim Countrow As Integer = 1
        Dim AmountTotal As Decimal = 0

        For Each row As DataGridView In dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows
            Countrow += 1
            AmountTotal += row.Cells(4).Value  // give correct price column index
        Next
               txtGrossTotal.Text = AmountTotal.ToString()
    End Sub
```

Comment: amounttotal+=row.cells(4).value this line not accepting."cells is not a member of system.windows.forms.datagridview"

Comment: @NAJEEB Use `AmountTotal += row.Cells(4).Value.ToDecimal()`

Comment: problem is its not accepting the "cells" row.cells.                 Error 'Cells' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'.

Comment: I think @SATSON made a mistake. It should be `For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows`

Comment: dotnet.4.0 this is what u asking? vs 2010.express

Comment: @equisde , you are right, that's it... now its working, thanks a lot both of you. and you are really great. please help me next time if I get any error please. thanks again equisde.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub Calculate()
    Dim Countrow As Integer = 1
    Dim AmountTotal As Decimal = 0

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows
        Countrow += 1
        AmountTotal += row.Cells(4).Value
    Next
    txtGrossTotal.Text = AmountTotal.ToString()
End Sub
```

@equisde you are the hero, this is the correct code.

Comment: Say thanks to @SATSON. He gave the answer. I just corrected a mistake. Please feel free to accept SATSON's answer.